# writing custom string class in c++

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to write a basic string class for practice, and I am struggling with the `reserve()` function to increase my char array's memory allocation.

This is the error message I get:

> free(): double free detected in tcache 2

This is my approach:

```
void string::reserve(size_t n)
{
    if (n <= space+1) return; // never decrease allocation
    char *p = new char[n+1]; // allocate new space
    for (int i=0; i<sz; ++i) p[i]=pChars[i]; // copy old elements
    //strcpy(p, pChars); // didn't work either
    p[n] = '\0';
    delete[] pChars; // deallocate old space
    pChars = p;
    space = n+1;
}
```

I will also share a picture of my header file below:

[image]

Here is the entire code:

```
#include "String.h"
namespace String
{
    string::string(): sz(0), pChars(nullptr), space(0) {}
    string::string(const char* s): sz(strlen(s)), pChars(new char[strlen(s)+1]), space(sz+1)          ///Constructor using a null-terminated C String
    {
        //for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) pChars[i] = s[i];
        strcpy(pChars,s);
        pChars[strlen(s)] = '\0';
    }
    string::string(const string& s): sz(s.sz), pChars(new char[s.sz]), space(s.sz)        ///copy constructor
    {
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i<s.sz; i++) pChars[i] = s.pChars[i];
        pChars[s.sz] = '\0';
    }
    string& string::operator=(const string& s)     ///copy assignment
    {
        if (this==&s) return *this; // self-assignment, no work needed
        if (s.sz<=space) 
            { // enough space, no need for new allocation
                for (size_t i = 0; i<s.sz; ++i) pChars[i] = s.pChars[i]; // copy elements
                sz = s.sz;
                return *this;
            }
        char *p = new char [s.sz]; // copy and swap
        for (size_t i = 0; i<s.sz; ++i) p[i] = s.pChars[i];
        delete[] pChars;
        sz = s.sz;
        space = s.sz;
        pChars = p;
        return *this; 
    } 
    string& string:: operator=(const char* s)       ///copy assignment using a null-terminated C String
    {
        char *p = new char[strlen(s)+1];
        for(size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) p[i] = s[i];
        p[sz] = '\0';
        delete [] pChars;
        sz = strlen(s);
        space = sz;
        strcpy(pChars, p);
        return *this;     

    }
    ///string(string&& s);                  ///move constructor, not needed (compiler copy elision)
    string& string:: operator=(string&& s)         ///move assignment
    {
        delete[] pChars; // deallocate old space
        pChars = s.pChars;  // copy a's elem and sz
        sz = s.sz;
        space = s.space;
        s.pChars = nullptr; // make a the empty vector
        s.sz = 0;
        cout << "Move" << endl;
        return *this;        
    }
    string::~string()
    {
        delete [] pChars;
    }
    char& string:: operator[](size_t pos) {return pChars[pos];}            ///set operator
    const char& string:: operator[](size_t pos) const {return pChars[pos];}   ///get operator

    void string::reserve(size_t n)
    {
        if (n <= space+1) return; // never decrease allocation
        char *p = new char[n+1]; // allocate new space
        for (int i=0; i<sz; ++i) p[i]=pChars[i]; // copy old elements
        //strcpy(p, pChars);
        p[sz] = '\0';
        delete[] pChars; // deallocate old space
        pChars = p;
        space = n+1;
    }
    void string:: push_back(const char c)                   ///push char c to the end
    {
        if (sz==0)  // no space: grab some
        reserve(8);
        else if (sz==space)  // no more free space: get more space
        reserve(2*space);
        pChars[sz] = c; // add d at end
        ++sz; // and increase the size (sz is the number of elements)

    }



    bool operator==(const string& lhs, const string& rhs)  ///check equality (same size, all chars the same)
    {
        if (lhs.size() != rhs.size()) return false;
        else
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i<lhs.size(); i++)
            {
                if (lhs[i] != rhs[i]) return false;
            }
            
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool operator==(const string& lhs, const char* rhs)    ///equality with null terminated C string
    {
        if(lhs.size() == strlen(rhs))
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i< lhs.size(); i++)
            {
                if(lhs[i] == rhs[i]) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool operator>(const string& lhs, const string& rhs)   ///greater than operator, true if lhs > rhs
    {

    }
    string operator+(const string& lhs, const string& rhs) ///concatenate two MyStrings, return the result
    {

    }
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const string& s)
    {

        for (size_t i = 0; i<s.size(); i++)
            {
                os << s[i];
            }
        return os;
    }
    istream& operator>>(istream& is, string& s)
    {
        char c;
        while(is.get(c))
        {
            if (c!=' ') s.push_back(c);
        }
        return is;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Why `p[n] = '\0';` instead of `p[sz] = '\0';`? This might be a reason why `strcpy` did not work.

Comment: use a naming convention for your data members

Comment: I suggest using `std::vector` in the custom string class.

Comment: you seem to have trashed your heap elsewhere, we gonna need to see the rest of the code

Comment: Just my two cents. Providing move assignment and not move constructor is an odd design choice.

Comment: @pm100 I have update the rest of the code, If you could please have a look. appreciate it

Comment: it would be nice to have the header and a test main - debugging by just reading code is tedious. One serious error found so far

Answer (score 2):

First error

```
string::string(const string& s): sz(s.sz), pChars(new char[s.sz]), space(s.sz)        ///copy constructor
{
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i<s.sz; i++) pChars[i] = s.pChars[i];
    pChars[s.sz] = '\0';
}
```

This allocates an array of s.sz chars and then writes off the end of it

SHould be

```
string::string(const string& s): sz(s.sz), pChars(new char[s.sz] + 1), space(s.sz)        ///copy constructor
{
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i<s.sz; i++) pChars[i] = s.pChars[i];
    pChars[s.sz] = '\0';
}
```